# Improving SQLite Query Performance

Tags: sqlite

I have run the following query in SQLite and SQLServer. On SQLite the query has never finished runing - i have let it sit for hours and still continues to run. On SQLServer it takes a little less than a minute to run. The table has several hundred thousands of records. Is there a way to improve the performance of the query in SQLite?

```
update tmp_tbl
   set prior_symbol = (select o.symbol
                         from options o
                        where o.underlying_ticker = tmp_tbl.underlying_ticker
                          and o.option_type = tmp_tbl.option_type
                          and o.expiration = tmp_tbl.expiration
                          and o.strike = (select max(o2.strike)
                                            from options o2
                                           where o2.underlying_ticker = tmp_tbl.underlying_ticker
                                             and o2.option_type = tmp_tbl.option_type
                                             and o2.expiration = tmp_tbl.expiration
                                             and o2.strike < tmp_tbl.strike));
```

Update: I was able to get what I needed done using some python code and handling the data mapping outside of SQL. However, I am puzzled by the performance difference between SQLite and SQLServer - I was expecting SQLite to be much faster.

When I ran the above query initially, neither table had any indexes other than a standard primary key, id, which is unrelated to the data. I created two indexes as follows:

```
create index options_table_index on options(underlying_ticker, option_type, expiration, strike);
```

and:

```
create index tmp_tbl_index on tmp_tbl(underlying_ticker, option_type, expiration, strike);
```

But that didn't help. The query still continues to clock without any output - I let it run for nearly 40 minutes.

The table definition for tmp_tbl is:

```html
create table tmp_tbl(id integer primary key,
                     symbol text,
                     underlying_ticker text,
                     option_type text,
                     strike real,
                     expiration text,
                     mid real,
                     prior_symbol real,
                     prior_premium real,
                     ratio real,
                     error_flag bit);
```

The definition of options table is similar but with a few more fields.

Comment: Do you have indexes defined for your `where` fields?

Comment: Yes, please show us more of your schema (tables and indices) so that we can see what's going on. Also, what does `explain query plan put_the_query_here` output?

Comment: Hot Licks, I ran the query after creating indexes, but the performance of the query is still not what I was expecting. Given that there are only 370k records in the table, I expect this query to be rather fast - a few seconds at most.
Cameron - I am not sure what you are referring to. This is the first time I post a question so it is likely that I included something by mistake.